# Create 2 digit barcode for IDAutomationHC39M but not scanning

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I am trying to generating IDAutomationHC39M for number 50 or 51 the barcode for that gets generated but on scanning I am not able to get the Detail number for that.

**Same way I am able to create the barcode for 14757 and in that case I am able to scan that barcode properly.**

**How should I scan 2 digit generated Barcodes.**

Is there some thing I am doing wrong in below code.

```
public void generateBarcode(int id)
    {
        if (plBarCode != null)
        {
            string barCode = "";

            barCode = Convert.ToString(id);
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 70, 70))
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
                {
                    Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 30);
                    PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                    SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);                       
                    int w = barCode.Length * 40;                    
                    Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap);                    
                    PointF oPoint = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                    SolidBrush oBrushWrite = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);         
                    oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);                       
                    oGraphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont, oBrushWrite, oPoint);

                }
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                    Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                    imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                }
                plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
            }
        }

    }
```

Generated the below barcode with number 56 and also removed * from the passing string still on scanning not returning the data 56.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure to have enough room for the barcode? DrawString might use more room than expected.

Comment: `If you are attempting to encode a small amount of characters, it may be a good idea to be sure that your scanner is capable of scanning the minimum amount, as many are set to read a minimum of 4 characters in a barcode` : http://idautomation.blogspot.nl/2011/07/top-5-reasons-why-barcode-font-wont.html ;-)

Comment: Btw, I am not sure if this includes the `*` marks.

Comment: @Stefan I think * mark is used to get starting and ending point of barcode and yes my scanner is capable to scan the minimum value

Comment: @Stefan i had generated online code39 barcode and it was scanning properly for 2 digit , Is there a difference for generating the IDAutomationHC39M barcode and code 39 barcode?

Comment: I have to say, I am no expert on the subject, so I am afraid I can't help you out :-/  I was just passing by, and noticed your earlier question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this modified code.

```
public void generateBarcode(string id)
{
                int w = id.Length * 55;

                // Create a bitmap object of the width that we calculated and height of 100
                Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(w, 100);
                // then create a Graphic object for the bitmap we just created.
                Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap);
                // Now create a Font object for the Barcode Font
                // (in this case the IDAutomationHC39M) of 18 point size
                Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 18);
                // Let's create the Point and Brushes for the barcode
                PointF oPoint = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush oBrushWrite = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                // Now lets create the actual barcode image
                // with a rectangle filled with white color
                oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);
                // We have to put prefix and sufix of an asterisk (*),
                // in order to be a valid barcode
                oGraphics.DrawString("*" + id + "*", oFont, oBrushWrite, oPoint);
                // Then we send the Graphics with the actual barcode
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();

                using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/img/barcodes/") + id + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    oBitmap.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                }
                oBitmap.Dispose();
                imgbarcode.ImageUrl = "~/img/barcodes/"+id+".jpg";
}
```

Comment: your given code is working perfectly but can u say how to delete the down text from generated image. Please review this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181783/generating-idautomationhc39m-barcode-is-generating-well-but-need-to-remove-value/46187309#46187309

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have 6 characters there. Two '*' characters start and end the barcode.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATUoCA+Jw8kAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARVICA/z3WM0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATUoCA+Jw8kAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAak4DA7VAmk0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUUoCA+juoggAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATVICAxOyzrMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAizUEAhrxcbgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbkoDA3iPVH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajUDAvnk9E4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="40">
```

I get this when I plug 50 in. Looks like you need to remove the two asterisks you are adding before and after barCode in the 'DrawString' method.

Here is my added image.

[image]

Comment: I currently I have tried to generate barcode with number 56 and also removed the * but still not scanning. I have updated the question please review

Comment: Also can u use my code and generate the barcode so that if any other issue is there u can get me the perfect answer

Comment: I'd like to help you debug the code, but I do not use C# or .net, I use JavaScript. You almost have it, now. It looks like your code is cutting off the right side of the barcode. I have added an image to my answer for you to see it more clearly.

Comment: which code are u using to generate this barcode? can u provide that

Comment: My code is at http://brian-p-anderson.github.io/JS-Barcodes/  (Enter text you want, set the height to 40 or so. set the width to 10, default is Code 3 of 9, so just have to press the "Generate Barcode" button.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
  protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        string barCode = txtCode.Text;
        //testbar.Text = txtCode.Text;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();

        using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 28, 90))
        {

            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
            {
                var fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
                fonts.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("~/font/IDAutomationHC39M.ttf"));
                Font oFont = new Font((FontFamily)fonts.Families[0], 17f);
                //Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 10,FontStyle.Regular,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont , blackBrush, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
            }
            plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
        }
    }
```