# Generating IDAutomationHC39M barcode is generating well but need to remove value

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

Hi I am using below code and the bar code is generating well but how can I remove text written down to label.

```
 public void generateBarcode(string id)
    {
        int w = id.Length * 55;
        Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(w, 100);
        Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap);
        Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 18);
        PointF oPoint = new PointF(2f, 2f);
        SolidBrush oBrushWrite = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);
        oGraphics.DrawString("*" + id + "*", oFont, oBrushWrite, oPoint);
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();

        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/img/barcodes/") + id + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
        {
            oBitmap.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        }
        oBitmap.Dispose();
        imgbarcode.ImageUrl = "~/img/barcodes/" + id + ".jpg";
}
```

My bar code is generating as below. Here I need to remove the bar code text as *76*

[image]

Comment: So, is the "oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);" line supposed to draw a white rectangle over the bottom text?

Comment: @BrianAnderson so what changes I need to do to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you tried moving the "oGraphics.FillRectangle(..." line below the "oGraphics.DrawString(..."? That's what I would try next, anyway.

Comment: @BrianAnderson U MEAN   oGraphics.DrawString("*" + id + "*", oFont, oBrushWrite, oPoint);
            oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);

Comment: Yep, did you try switching the order of those two lines?

Comment: @BrianAnderson BLANK IMAGE IS COMING

Comment: @BrianAnderson buit changing oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100); to oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 80); one bold black strip is showing on text * 76 * which is hiding the * 76 * text showing on image

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.idautomation.com/free-barcode-products/code39-font/#Specifications), the font you need to use without text is "IDAutomationC39M". Unfortunately, that's not in the free version.

Comment: but according to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057092/create-2-digit-barcode-for-idautomationhc39m-but-not-scanning I was able to create the bar code without text and that without free version. The only issue in this code was that it was creating wrong bar codes for 2-3 digit number